# Date Format changes from dd/MM/yyyy to dd_MM_yyyy after downloading the attachment from email

Tags: java, gmail

I have stuck in a date format issue. I have sent a mail from Java code with date format as dd/MM/yyyy and mail received successfully. When I checked the attachment the date format is correct, but when I download the attachment, date format changes to dd_MM_yyyy.

I have checked in windows and Linux OS, but the issue remains same. As per my understanding there is no issue in the code.

Attachment Image:

[image]

Downloaded image:

[image]

Please look into the attached files, highlighted in Red Rectangles

Please help me over this.

Comment: I think no OS accepts `dd/MM/yyyy ` as a valid file name.

Comment: @ernest_k Definitely. I think you can post it as an answer.

Comment: yes @ernest_k, you are correct. I tried to save simple txt file and got error in both OS. Thanks.

Comment: This requirement has been raised from client end, Is there any way to achieve this. @amseager.

Comment: @ernest_k same to you as well

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to achieve this is to use "very similar" symbols to the forward slash, f.e. this one: [Division slash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215/index.htm).

But speaking about using the "real slash" in file names - no, it's not possible in both Windows and Linux.